# How do I input a list of values into a 2d array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

**Input:** A dictionary of lists.

```
{'5': ['2', '4', '8'], '6': ['3', '1', '7'], '9': ['4', '8'], '3': ['2', '4'], '1': ['2'], '8': ['2'], '7': ['4'], '2':[], '4':[]}
```

**Output:** A 2d array

**Code:**

```
def preprocess(p=p):
    """
    This function creates a sparse table of 2^ith ancestor of the node
    """
    N = int(len(p))
    LEVEL = int(ceil(log(N)))
    P = [[-1 for i in range(LEVEL)] for node in range(N+1)]
    for node in range(0, N):
        #print(node)
        P[int(node + 1)][0] = p[str(int(node)+ 1)]
        if P[int(node + 1)][0] == []:
            P[int(node + 1)][0] = [str(int(node)+ 1)]
    for i in range(1, LEVEL):
        for node in range(N + 1):
            #print("node", node, "i", i)
            if P[node][i-1] != -1:
                #print("node not equal -1:", node, "i", i, i - 1)
                inside = P[node][i-1] # this wont work for dags
                print("inside", inside, type(inside))
                P[node][i] = P[int(inside)][i-1]
    return P
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

How do I push a list into a 2d array such that P[node][i] = ['3', '2', etc]?

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

On the line with `P[int(node + 1)][0] = [str(int(node)+ 1)]` I think you meant `P[int(node + 1)][0] = p[str(int(node)+ 1)]`. otherwise you assign a list to P[][] and pass it to int(...).